# Reduce path with valid regex in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I need to have an unilateral function in mod_rewrite which giving a path produce a prefix using only a regex, unfortunately I have no control whatsoever on implementing this system.

I can only produce a regex and give it to the system administrator.

What I need is a regex pattern which is reducing a path in a two char prefix as follows

1. case point: "abc.cde" -> "ac" (first char of first word and first char of second word)
2. case minus: "abc-cde" -> "ac" (same as above)
3. case point and minus after point: "abc.cde-fgh" -> "ac"
4. case minus and point after minus: "abc-cde.fgh" -> "af"
5. case no point and no minus: "random" -> "ra" (take first two char)

I saw that there is a tester on regrex for mod_rewrite [here](https://www.regextester.com/97698)

Comment: The request url we'll be somethings like: http://myhost.my/abc.cde-fgh

Comment: Are you looking for external redirect with `R` flag or just internal rewrite?

Comment: External redirect, so if i get this: http://myhost.my/abc.cde-fgh i have to call that: http://myhost2.my/ac/abc.cde-fgh

Comment: Yes exactly, any possible string

Comment: Try my answer below and let me know if any case doesn't work

Comment: Yes i'm working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w)\w*[.-](\w)\w*/?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(\w)[\w-]*\.(\w) /$1$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(\w)(\w)[^.-]+$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can you please write how would it be without redirect rule, just internal rewrite

Comment: Just remove `,R=301` from all these rules.

Comment: check it, it actually does not work properly because the $1$2 is not considering the other cases, where there is a minus before a point and a random word with no points and minuses

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the letters you need using "capturing groups" (parentheses), and connect the three alternatives that you may encounter with `|`. The alternatives are: first a filename with a point `\.`, then with a minus `-` (but no point, because we go to the second alternative if the first one didn't match), then the rule for words without any minuses and points (after the first two alternatives didn't match):

```
s/(.).*\.(.).*|(.).*-(.).*|(..).*/$1$2$3$4$5/
```

https://regexr.com/3r2to

Comment: Thanks look really promising, is there a way to improve the expression in order to get the first two chars from any possible word and not just "ra" from word "random"

Comment: Sure, for example `s/(.).*\.(.).*|(.).*-(.).*|(..).*/$1$2$3$4$5/`

Comment: This is wonderfull, exactly what i needed, can you please edit your answer and set as solution? Thanks again!